# ansible unable to ssh but manual ssh successful

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am trying to ping remote host using module: ping. my hosts file looks like below:

> [groupA] 
>  HostA ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=userA

command: `ansible -i hosts -m ping all`
Manually I am able to ssh successfully using same userA on HostA, but not via ansible 
Debug logs from ansible:

> No config file found; using defaults 
>  Loaded callback minimal of
>   type stdout, v2.0 
>   ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER:
>   userA 
>   SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
>   -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=userA -o ConnectTimeout=10 HostA '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo
>   /tmp/ansible-userB/ansible-tmp-1473143642.15-125405279117948`" &&
>   echo ansible-tmp-1473143642.15-125405279117948="`echo
>   /tmp/ansible-userB/ansible-tmp-1473143642.15-125405279117948`" ) &&
>   sleep 0'"'"''

Source Host O.S details:

> LSB Version:   
>   :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch 
>   Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer Description:    Red Hat 
>   Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago) Release:        6.8 
>   Codename:       Santiago

Target Host O.S details:

> bash-4.1$ lsb_release -a 
>   LSB Version:
>   :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
>   
>  Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer 
>  Description:    Red
>   Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago) 
>  Release:
>   6.8 
>  Codename:       Santiago

EDIT: Manual commands:

```
ssh UserA@HostA
//Some lines of sshing to the remote host
-sh$: hostname -f
HostA
-sh$:
```

EDIT2: 
Output from running ssh: EXEC command

> OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 debug1: Reading
>   configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: Applying options for *
>   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0 debug1: Connecting to hostA [IP port]
>   port 22. debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK debug1: fd 3 clearing
>   O_NONBLOCK debug1: Connection established. debug3: timeout: 9924 ms
>   remain after connect debug1: identity file /home/userB/.ssh/identity
>   type -1 debug1: identity file /home/userB/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
>   debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/userB/.ssh/id_rsa. debug2:
>   key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN' debug3: key_read:
>   missing keytype debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read:
>   missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
>   key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
>   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing
>   whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read:
>   missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
>   key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
>   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing
>   whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read:
>   missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
>   key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
>   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing
>   whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3: key_read:
>   missing whitespace debug3: key_read: missing whitespace debug3:
>   key_read: missing whitespace debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key
>   type '-----END' debug3: key_read: missing keytype debug1: identity
>   file /home/userB/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 debug1: identity file
>   /home/userB/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /home/userB/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /home/userB/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /home/userB/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: identity file
>   /home/userB/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: Remote protocol version
>   2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH* debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3 debug2: fd 3 setting
>   O_NONBLOCK debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a
>   total of 981 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
>   reserved 0 debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
>   ssh-rsa,ssh-dss debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
>   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
>   none,zlib@openssh.com debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: debug2:
>   kex_parse_kexinit: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
>   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 debug2: mac_setup: found
>   hmac-md5 debug1: kex: server->client  debug2: mac_setup: found
>   hmac-md5 debug1: kex: client->server  debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent debug1: expecting
>   SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
>   debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 123/256 debug2: bits set:
>   506/1024 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent debug1: expecting
>   SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
>   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host hostA filename
>   /home/userB/.ssh/known_hosts debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host
>   hostA filename /home/userB/.ssh/known_hosts debug3:
>   check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1 debug3: check_host_in_hostfile:
>   host IP port filename /home/userB/.ssh/known_hosts debug3:
>   check_host_in_hostfile: host IP port filename
>   /home/userB/.ssh/known_hosts debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match
>   line 1 debug1: Host 'hostA' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/userB/.ssh/known_hosts:1 debug2: bits set:
>   505/1024 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct debug2:
>   kex_derive_keys debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a
>   total of 1165 debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   received debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug3: Wrote 48 bytes
>   for a total of 1213 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug2: key:
>   /home/userB/.ssh/identity ((nil)) debug2: key: /home/userB/.ssh/id_rsa
>   (0x7ffb0551e430) debug2: key: /home/userB/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)) debug2:
>   key: /home/userB/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)) debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a
>   total of 1277 debug3: input_userauth_banner
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue:  debug3: start over, passed
>   a different list  debug3: preferred  debug3: authmethod_lookup
>   gssapi-with-mic debug3: remaining preferred:  debug3:
>   authmethod_is_enabled  debug1: Next authentication method:  debug3:
>   Trying to reverse map address IP port. debug1: Unspecified GSS
>   failure.  Minor code may provide more information Credentials cache
>   file '/tmp/krb5cc_' not found
>
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
>   information Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_' not found
>
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
>   information
>
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
>   information Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_' not found
>
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method debug3:
>   authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex debug3: remaining preferred:  debug3:
>   authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex debug1: Next authentication method:
>   gssapi-keyex debug1: No valid Key exchange context debug2: we did not
>   send a packet, disable method debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
>   debug3: remaining preferred: ,publickey debug3: authmethod_is_enabled
>   publickey debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Trying
>   private key: /home/userB/.ssh/identity debug3: no such identity:
>   /home/userB/.ssh/identity debug1: Offering public key:
>   /home/userB/.ssh/id_rsa debug3: send_pubkey_test debug2: we sent a
>   publickey packet, wait for reply debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total
>   of 1645 debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277 debug2:
>   input_userauth_pk_ok:  debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey:  debug1: read PEM
>   private key done: type RSA debug3: Wrote 640 bytes for a total of 2285
>   debug1: Enabling compression at level 6. debug1: Authentication
>   succeeded (publickey). debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] debug3:
>   ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0 debug2: channel 0: send open debug1:
>   Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com debug1: Entering interactive
>   session. debug3: Wrote 112 bytes for a total of 2397 debug2: callback
>   start debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0 debug2: channel 0: request
>   pty-req confirm 1 debug1: Sending environment. debug3: Ignored env 
>   debug3: Ignored env  debug3: Ignored env MANPATH debug3: Ignored env 
>   debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME debug3: Ignored env
>   ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING debug3: Ignored env ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS debug3:
>   Ignored env  debug3: Ignored env TERM debug3: Ignored env SHELL
>   debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE debug3: Ignored env QTDIR debug3: Ignored
>   env OLDPWD debug3: Ignored env QTINC debug3: Ignored env USER debug3:
>   Ignored env ANSIBLE_REMOTE_TEMP debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS debug3:
>   Ignored env  debug3: Ignored env TMOUT debug3: Ignored env  debug3:
>   Ignored env PAGER debug3: Ignored env PATH debug3: Ignored env 
>   debug3: Ignored env PWD debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME debug3: Ignored
>   env *LMFILES* debug3: Ignored env EFS_SERVERNAME debug3: Ignored env
>   EDITOR debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8 debug2: channel 0:
>   request env confirm 0 debug3: Ignored env MODULEPATH debug3: Ignored
>   env  debug3: Ignored env LOADEDMODULES debug3: Ignored env
>   ANSIBLE_SCP_IF_SSH debug3: Ignored env ANSIBLE_TRANSPORT debug3:
>   Ignored env HISTCONTROL debug3: Ignored env  debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
>   debug3: Ignored env HOME debug3: Ignored env  debug3: Ignored env
>   PYTHONPATH debug3: Ignored env PBUSER debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
>   debug3: Ignored env QTLIB debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH debug3: Ignored
>   env LESSOPEN debug3: Ignored env EFS_PLATFORM64 debug3: Ignored env
>   G_BROKEN_FILENAMES debug3: Ignored env BASH_FUNC_append() debug3:
>   Ignored env BASH_FUNC_addpath() debug3: Ignored env BASH_FUNC_module()
>   debug3: Ignored env BASH_FUNC_prepend() debug3: Ignored env
>   BASH_FUNC_delpath() debug3: Ignored env BASH_FUNC_showpath() debug3:
>   Ignored env _ debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1 debug2: fd 3
>   setting TCP_NODELAY debug2: callback done debug2: channel 0: open
>   confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768 debug3: Wrote 320 bytes for a total of
>   2717 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0 debug2: PTY
>   allocation request accepted on channel 0 debug2: channel 0: rcvd
>   adjust 2097152 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
>   debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0 Last login: Tue Sep  6
>   07:24:55 2016 from hostB

Comment: Is there an error message or it just hangs? What's the OS on target host?

Comment: What type of authentication do you use?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov It just hangs. But via manual ssh it does not hangs. I am using ssh no-pass authentication

Comment: What's happen if you execute line after `SSH: EXEC` manually from shell?

Comment: sorry is that a command u would want me to execute. I have executed the commands as posted in OP.

Comment: He is asking, "what happens if you try running the same `ssh` command line as ansible?".  Ansible shows you this in the line that starts with `SSH: EXEC`. Everything after that is the ssh command.  Maybe try running simply `ssh -C -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=userA -o ConnectTimeout=10 HostA` and see what sort of errors you get?

Comment: Ran..No errors..pasted output from that command in OP

Comment: Check /var/log/auth.log on your target server to understand if something is written during connection attempt from ansible ontrol machine.

Comment: No such file exists..should there be a file in that location with that name even if we do manual ssh? i don't see such file getting created via manual ssh..and neither do i see such file on other hosts where i am able to ssh via ansible

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to skip the authentication of ssh?
In the file /etc/ssh/ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config, add following lines.

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

or add following lines in the ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

Comment: so you want me to skip ssh authentication, i thought that was the purpose of ssh